# How to stop a recursion in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have the facts:

```
arePerpendicular(line([q, r]), line([r, s])).
arePerpendicular(line([p, s]), line([r, s])).
arePerpendicular(line([p, q]), line([p, s])).
% pqrs is a rectangle
```

And since I want perpendicular() to be symmetric, I use:

```
perpendicular(line([P, Q]), line([R, S])) :-
   arePerpendicular(line([P, Q]), line([R, S]));
   arePerpendicular(line([R, S]), line([P, Q]));
   arePerpendicular(line([Q, P]), line([R, S]));
   arePerpendicular(line([Q, P]), line([S, R])).
```

Then I include the rule:

```
parallel(line(A), line(B)) :-
   perpendicular(line(A), line(C)),
   perpendicular(line(B), line(C)).
```

So far it is working as intended. But when I include:

```
perpendicular(line(B), line(C)) :-
   parallel(line(A), line(B)),
   perpendicular(line(A), line(C)).
```

it results in an infinite recursion. My goal is to let `perpendicular()` and `parallel()` to be able to derive every combination of lines which are perpendicular or parallel. For example, `perpendicular(line([p,q]), line([q,r]))` should return true.

Comment: Would it be a surprise to get infinite recursion when you define `parallel/2` and `perpendicular/2` to each be defined in terms of each other?